# Why is my function failing this particular test case?

Tags: c, math, if-statement

My function should calculate this value when x and y are on the interval [1, 20]. The irrigation exposure cannot be higher than 10 and when x and y aren't on the correct interval, you return -1.

If my explanation for the function wasn't clear enough here it is on paper:
[image]

For the case where x and y are both 6, it says that it's 0.000000. But when I do the calculation by hand, I get the output -1. I'm not sure what's wrong with my code and I can't figure out why this particular test case isn't working! Any help is appreciated.

Here's what I get when I ran the test cases:
[image]

Here are the test cases that I picked:
[image]

And here's my code for the function:
[image]

Comment: In the case when `waterexp > 10`, you return `irrexp` without assigning it a value (which I think is undefined behavior).

Comment: Are you sure the inputs are integers? Can they be real numbers?

Comment: Yes, legends2k, the inputs are integers. Oh! So Blender, if waterexp was greater than 10, in that case, I'd return a -1 right? Thanks for the help!

Comment: OH wait, actually, after rereading my instructions, I'm thinking, rather than returning -1 when waterexp is greater than 10, I return 10 when waterexp is greater than 10 because I want the smaller value. I'll try this, again, thanks for helping!

Comment: @Karen, if `waterexp` > 10, `irrexp` is not set to anything.  It could have any value.

Comment: For x and y equal 6, your test code seems to expect -1, but you get 0, and the answer should be 10, according to the formula. As others mentioned, you should set the value of irrexp in the case where waterexp>10. But maybe there is something more... How is defined that abs() you are using?

Comment: I advise you to do a  copy paste of your code and format it properly so it's easier to review and indeed a fancier way to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 main points:

- As was already mentionned, there are no provisions for the case that `waterexp > 10`.
- Your expectations are wrong: if `x == y`, `denominator = 1` and `waterexp = 12`, so you should get `10`. There is no reason for it to be `-1`.

I would have added even a code example if you had provided your code as code, not as a picture.